# Moving average of past 5-minutes data against each tick

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

This is my Data

```
             times  value   size    return
2016-06-01 9:07:11  14.2    595     0
2016-06-01 9:08:11  14.2    2505    0.003527341
2016-06-01 9:11:03  14.15   1       0
2016-06-01 9:13:03  14.15   2200    0.003527341
2016-06-01 9:15:04  14.2    480     0
2016-06-01 9:15:04  14.2    2965    0.003527341
2016-06-01 9:15:05  14.2    144     0
2016-06-01 9:20:05  14.2    1856    0.003514942
2016-06-01 9:22:06  14.25   300     0
2016-06-01 9:25:06  14.25   856     0.003514942
```

I want to create another column `"5min_Ret"` for each tick, whose value should be `last 5 mins average of return`. Below is the desired output with logic of calculation mentioned at the end of each row. Logic Column is just to explain here. It will be not added in final output.

```
             times  value   size    return      5min_Ret    Logic
2016-06-01 9:07:11  14.2    595     0           0           First Tick 0
2016-06-01 9:08:11  14.2    2505    0.003527341 0.001763671 Avg of 1 to 2
2016-06-01 9:11:03  14.15   1       0           0.00117578  Avg of 1 to 3
2016-06-01 9:13:03  14.15   2200    0.003527341 0.002351561 Avg of 2 to 4
2016-06-01 9:15:04  14.2    480     0           0.00117578  Avg of 3 to 5
2016-06-01 9:15:04  14.2    2965    0.003527341 0.001763671 Avg of 3 to 6
2016-06-01 9:15:05  14.2    144     0           0.001410936 Avg of 3 to 7
2016-06-01 9:20:05  14.2    1856    0.003514942 0.001757471 Avg of 7 to 8
2016-06-01 9:22:06  14.25   300     0           0.001757471 Avg of 8 to 9
2016-06-01 9:25:06  14.25   856     0.003514942 0.001757471 Avg of 9 to 10
```

I assume `dplyr` package will be useful for group by. But for each tick I am not able to be successful to get group by data by interval 5 mins. Any suggestion/help in R is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide data in a copy/pasteable form and also show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `sapply`. Let's say your object is called `df`:

```
df$'5min_ret' <- sapply( X = seq_along( df$return ), 
                        FUN = function(x) { 
                            mean( df$return[ df$times >= df$times[x] - 5*60 & 
                                                   df$times <= df$times[x] ] ) 
                        } )
```

Note the `seq_along` call is simply creating a vector sequence the same length as the number of rows in your data frame (in your case, 10).

The function defined after `FUN` is what's important. That function takes a subset of the dataframe where the time is within the last 5 mins (greater than 5mins ago, and less than now), and takes the mean of the `return` column that's left. `sapply` simply runs that function for every value of `X` (that's our 1:10 sequence).

NOTE however that calling your column `5min_ret` is generally not a great idea, since R doesn't particularly like names of that form. I've surrounded it in quotations on creation to get around that, but I'd recommend thinking of a different name.

Comment: this is great solution!! and a simple approach too! I was busy trying to figure out the dplyr approach which I guess is not needed.

Comment: thanks @joel.wilson ! I did spend a few minutes down the dplyr path too, but it's always good to have base R floating around in the back of your mind :)

Comment: perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = data.frame(times = c("2016-06-01 9:07:11", "2016-06-01 9:08:11", "2016-06-01 9:11:03", "2016-06-01 9:13:03","2016-06-01 9:15:04 ","2016-06-01 9:15:04", "2016-06-01 9:15:05",
                           "2016-06-01 9:20:05", "2016-06-01 9:22:06", "2016-06-01 9:25:06"),
                 return = c( 0, 0.003527341, 0, 0.003527341, 0, 0.003527341, 0, 0.003514942, 0, 0.003514942))
df$times = as.POSIXct(df$times)
df
             times      return
1  2016-06-01 09:07:11 0.000000000
2  2016-06-01 09:08:11 0.003527341
3  2016-06-01 09:11:03 0.000000000
4  2016-06-01 09:13:03 0.003527341
5  2016-06-01 09:15:04 0.000000000
6  2016-06-01 09:15:04 0.003527341 
7  2016-06-01 09:15:05 0.000000000
8  2016-06-01 09:20:05 0.003514942
9  2016-06-01 09:22:06 0.000000000
10 2016-06-01 09:25:06 0.003514942

# another dataframe for the start/end timeframe
df1  = data.frame("start" = df$times - 5*60, "end" = as.POSIXct(df$times))
df1
          start                 end 
1  2016-06-01 09:02:11 2016-06-01 09:07:11
2  2016-06-01 09:03:11 2016-06-01 09:08:11
3  2016-06-01 09:06:03 2016-06-01 09:11:03
4  2016-06-01 09:08:03 2016-06-01 09:13:03
5  2016-06-01 09:10:04 2016-06-01 09:15:04
6  2016-06-01 09:10:04 2016-06-01 09:15:04
7  2016-06-01 09:10:05 2016-06-01 09:15:05
8  2016-06-01 09:15:05 2016-06-01 09:20:05
9  2016-06-01 09:17:06 2016-06-01 09:22:06
10 2016-06-01 09:20:06 2016-06-01 09:25:06

library(dplyr)
df.mean <- df1 %>% 
   group_by(start, end) %>% 
   summarize(ret.mean = mean(df$return[df$times >= start & df$times <= end]))
df.mean
Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: start [?]

            start                 end    ret.mean
           (time)              (time)       (dbl)
1 2016-06-01 09:02:11 2016-06-01 09:07:11 0.000000000
2 2016-06-01 09:03:11 2016-06-01 09:08:11 0.001763670
3 2016-06-01 09:06:03 2016-06-01 09:11:03 0.001175780
4 2016-06-01 09:08:03 2016-06-01 09:13:03 0.002351561
5 2016-06-01 09:10:04 2016-06-01 09:15:04 0.001763670
6 2016-06-01 09:10:05 2016-06-01 09:15:05 0.001410936
7 2016-06-01 09:15:05 2016-06-01 09:20:05 0.001757471
8 2016-06-01 09:17:06 2016-06-01 09:22:06 0.001757471
9 2016-06-01 09:20:06 2016-06-01 09:25:06 0.001757471
```

You will find that the 5th and 6th group have been combined since they carry the same boundary. I have given step-by-step procedure so that you will be able to understand the approach. You can later have them all in a single dataframe

Comment: I am not planning to combine same boundary data. Because I have different plan about using this data. So I want to keep all ticks. My first priority is to keep the data count same.